# Property of inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How to prove that $\|x-y\| \geq |\|x\|-\|y\||$?

I am only thinking of for the LHS, $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 +(y_2-y_1)^2}$ but not sure how to manipulate that and how to handle the RHS.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the triangle inequality? If so $\|x\|=\|x-y+y\| \leq \|x-y\|+\|y\|$ so $\|x\|-\|y\| \leq \|x-y\|$ and $\|y\|=\|y-x+x\|\leq \|y-x\|+\|x\|=\|x-y\|+\|x\|$ so $\|y\|-\|x\| \leq \|x-y\|$. Thus $\pm(\|x\|-\|y\|) \leq \|x-y\|$.

Answer (score 6):

It is equivalent to the triangle inequality:
$$
\|x\|=\|(x-y)+y\|\le\|x-y\|+\|y\|
$$
Then subtract $\|y\|$ from both sides to get
$$
\|x\|-\|y\|\le\|x-y\|
$$
Similarly, we can show that
$$
\|y\|-\|x\|\le\|x-y\|
$$
to get
$$
|\|x\|-\|y\||\le\|x-y\|
$$